# Dynamic labels from database in zend form

Tags: forms, zend-framework, frameworks, label

I have a zend form with some elements. I want to have some dynamic labels on this form which should be populated from database. Which element should i use? Text? For example lats say i have a form to edit user data. I would like to have some labels to display values like userid, username etc.(this values should not be editable), and user description fields like phone, address etc.(these should be editable). Please give me some advice for this. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$form = new Zend_Form ();

$rows = array (
    array (
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => 'Phone'
    ),
    array (
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => 'Name'
    ),
);

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $form->addElement ($row ['type'], $row ['label'], array (
        'label' => $row ['label']
    ));
}

echo $form->render (new Zend_View ());
```